# bigz variable type from package gmp with ifelse()

Tags: r, gmp

Why does the following return this error?

```
> x <- as.bigz(5)
> y <- ifelse(1,x,0)
Error in ifelse(1, x, 0) : 
  incompatible types (from raw to logical) in subassignment type fix
```

I can get around it by doing

```
> x <- as.bigz(5)
> y <- as.bigz(ifelse(1,as.character(x),0))
```

It seems to have something to do with the fact that

```
> as.raw(5)
[1] 05
```

but

```
> as.raw(as.bigz(5))
 [1] 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00
```

Which suggests that ifelse() is doing a "as.raw" automatically.
Still though, if

```
> y <- as.raw(as.bigz(5))
> y
 [1] 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00
```

is possible, what is the difference?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. `ifelse(1, x, 0)` is equivalent to just saying `x[1]` since `1` always evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski He's providing a simple example to show what goes wrong with `bigz` inside `ifelse`

Comment: the use of `ifelse` as a short version of `if ... else ...` almost always turns against you and should be considered abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this means there is no `ifelse.bigz` method currently defined. `base::ifelse` doesn't understand `bigz` objects.

Instead, use `if ... else` , since `if(bigz_x [relationship operator] bigz_y)` will work because the relationship operators do have `bigz` methods, thus returning a logical value that `if` can work with.

```
Rgames> if(1) x else 0
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 5
```